# Axisymmetric fluid flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

I'm having trouble with a boundary condition.  In a fluid mechanics problem, I have flow at $z = \infty$ flowing into a solid plate at $z = 0$ and then flowing radially, and the problem is given as axisymmetric.  I know that the velocity field has $v_r$ and $v_z$, and $v_\theta = 0$.  How in the world would I express the symmetry boundary conditions without $\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

Axisymmetry implies that there is no change in anything in the $\theta$ direction, i.e.

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\text{anything}) = 0
$$

Which would mean

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial\theta} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial\theta} &= 0 \\
\implies &\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial\theta} = 0 \\
\implies &\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial\theta} = 0 \\
\implies &\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial\theta} = 0
\end{align}

Comment: I was trying to express the axisymmetry without utilizing theta, as mentioned above.  Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Axisymmetry is not a boundary condition, because there is no boundary in the $\theta$ direction. The conditions for axisymmetry, however, are used to simplify the Navier-Stoke equations and can not be denoted without $\theta$, because they are used to _eliminate_ $\theta$